# Navigate to def's in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

At the left side of PyCharm, where I have my project and filenames, I was till recently able to "fold open" a Python file like it was a directory and here I saw all classes and defs. This way I was able to navigate very easy.

A few days ago this suddenly stopped; now I just see the files and no longer the defs and classes.
I went through the entire list of settings (my god) but am not able to find how I can enable this... and without this option, I scroll myself an RSI.

Anyone an idea where this is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it back click the little "gear" icon in the project pane and select **Show Members**:

[image: project pane options menu]

You should then be able to "fold open" the files and see the classes and functions within:

[image: example of a file structure being displayed using this feature]

Here's the [relevant page from the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html) that talks about this feature. **Note that according to that page, this feature isn't available in the Educational version of PyCharm.**

Comment: Aaaaaah REALLY !!!   So simple xD xD xD   And I was really searching my ass off.
Thanks A LOT for your fast and super clear answer !!

Comment: So simple, yet so obscure at the same time. I had no idea this feature existed until now, so thank you for asking this question! I can see myself using this every day, and I'll bet it will save a lot of time now instead of scrolling myself into an RSI as you put it XD